# HTML anchor click event set variables

Tags: html, angular

I like set one more variable in HTML  click event, is it possible to set in the HTML tag itself?

```
<a class="collapse-toggle 
  ngclick" 
  (click)="collapse.oneTimePayment = !collapse.oneTimePayment, isOPelected=false " 
  [class.collapsed]="collapse.oneTimePayment">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `;` instead of `,` to separate statements

```
(click)="collapse.oneTimePayment = !collapse.oneTimePayment; isOPelected=false "
```

You should be aware that if the last expression evaluates to `false` as in your example `$event.preventDefault` is called.

Therefore it would probably be better to use

```
(click)="collapse.oneTimePayment = !collapse.oneTimePayment; isOPelected=false; null"
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I didn't know about the $event.preventDefault call